# Unable to create an array of wchar_t

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, wchar-t

In my code I have an array of wchar_t:

```
wchar_t paths [6] = {L"C:\\Program Files\\SomeAppsSuiteFolder1", L"C:\\Program Files\\SomeAppsSuiteFolder2", L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SomeAppsSuiteFolder1", L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SomeAppsSuiteFolder2", L"C:\\SomeAppsSuiteFolder1", L"C:\\SomeAppsSuiteFolder2"};
```

Later on I use the array in `for` loop. The problem is, that for this line I get following errors:

```
error: too many initializers for 'wchar_t [6]'
error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
```

What's more, in `for` loop I have `if` conditional like this one:

```
if(GetFileAttributesW(paths[i])!=INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {...}
```

And, again, I get an error here:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' [-fpermissive]
```

Strange enough, similar code used to compile correctly some months ago... What's the problem?

Comment: A `wchar_t` is just a wide character, not a string. You're attempting to initialize an array of characters with (wide) string values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need

```
const wchar_t* paths[6] = ....
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use:

```
wchar_t *paths[6] = ...
        ^
```

A `wchar_t` is a *single* (wide) character, not a string of them.

So, if you want an array of wide *strings,* you should use the pointer variant.

The declarator `wchar_t xyzzy[6]` gives you six *characters* rather than six character arrays.